# Documentation on writing hardware drivers

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening, I am working in the Biorobotics Lab at the National University of Mexico, my workmates and me are working with mobile domestic services robots made of custom hardware. I am getting interested in ROS as a tool to speed up robotics research, but our robots have hardware which is not covered in ROS. So I would like to know if there is any documentation on writing hardware drivers for ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10191/documentation-on-writing-hardware-drivers/) by [israelfigueroa](https://answers.ros.org/users/658/israelfigueroa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-06-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are quite a number of tutorials available for specific hardware (lasers, imu, Dynamixel servos) and general ROS message handling at http://www.ros.org/wiki/AllTutorials.

Some of the stacks supplied by other organizations include complete examples of working ROS code including hardware drivers (PR2, wubble, erratic, turtlebot, Pioneer P2OS), http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots.

There is a partially completed tutorial on writing a serial I/O hardware driver at http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20Simple%20Hardware%20Driver, but that won't help.

If you provide some more information regarding what particular devices you are interfacing to, then others can likely point you to the particular ROS stacks that are applicable.

Additional information:

Chad Rocky presented a guide to writing Hardware Drivers at ROSCon 2012 [program](http://roscon.ros.org/2012/?page_id=33), [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13yyOB5CXOzpvMa0_wYxDvNzjb_9dfMjDuVo-CvBcoRw/edit), [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pagC2WXT1x0)

Melonee Wise presented a guide to ROSifying a robot at ROSCon 2013: [program](http://roscon.ros.org/2013/?page_id=14),  [slides](http://roscon.ros.org/2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ROSCon2013_rosify_robot.pdf),  [video](https://vimeo.com/66966974)

---

Originally posted by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) with karma: 856 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually it is quite simple writing a hardware driver for ROS as it mainly is producing a message interface, and possibly diagnostics. That is, given, that you can write/modify a hardware driver not specific to ROS.

For examples you can see the links provided by Bart. There might also be (non-ROS) sample code for your hardware that you can easily modify.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2